# Unmarshal One to One Relationships in XML File

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

When I try to unmarshal my **Person.xml** to a **POJO** and print it out the parent object prints out fine but **ChildThree.java** prints out `null`?

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("src/xml/person.xml");
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Parent parent = (Parent) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(parent);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Person.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>
    <ChildOne>1</Child>
    <ChildTwo>2</Child>
    <ChildThree>
        <Name>3</Name>
        <Age>Ten</Age>
    </ChildThree>
</Parent>
```

**Parent.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Parent")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {

    @XmlElement
    private String ChildOne;
    @XmlElement
    private String ChildTwo;
    @XmlElement
    private ChildThree ChildThree;

    public String getChildOne() {
        return ChildOne;
    }

    public void setChildOne() {
        this.ChildOne = ChildOne;
    }

    public String getChildTwo() {
        return ChildTwo;
    }

    public void setChildTwo() {
        this.ChildTwo = ChildTwo;
    }


    public ChildThree getChildThree() {
        return ChildThree;
    }

    public void setChildThree() {
        this.ChildThree = ChildThree;
    }

}
```

**ChildThree.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ChildThree")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChildThree {

    @XmlElement
    private String Name;
    @XmlElement
    private String Age;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName() {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge() {
        this.Age = Age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should help:

1. When you specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class you should put your annotations on the field (instance variable) and not the property (get/set method), (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).
2. Make sure your get/set methods follow the appropriate bean conventions:

   - String getFoo()
   - void setFoo(String)
3. Recognize that JAXB has rules for converting field/property names in Java to XML names that may differ from your expectations.  When you have unmarshalling problems it is often useful to populate the object model and marshal it to see what JAXB is expecting (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html).

Comment: What does the XML look like when you marshal your model?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by replacing:

```
@XmlElement
private ChildThree ChildThree;
```

with:

```
@XmlElement(name = "ChildThree")
private List<ChildThree> childThree;
```